# Measure Magnetic Field Circuit

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

I saw a design of a magnetic field meter circuit at [here](https://www.electroschematics.com/magnetic-field-meter/).This circuit looks like it can measure weak magnetic field such as earth's with only using inductor coil to gather magnetic field and without using Hall-Effect special material plate? And, shouldn't the inductor coil must be rotated or moved in order to generate current from cutting magnetic field lines. The article does not say that :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The article states this is for sensing alternating magnetic fields in the 40 Hz to 10 kHz frequency range. Also stated, in the missing Figure 1, the sensor coil is simulated using an AC source. This could be used for sensing the magnetic field near power distribution systems.

Comment: I see. So, you cant measure earth magnetic field with that because its not oscillating?

Comment: That is correct, not suitable for measuring Earth's magnetic field. A fluxgate magnetometer sensor is a suitable device. There are articles on the Internet for building your own fluxgate magnetometer.

Comment: @JasmineSu maybe if you spin the circuit around!